# Taking a specific data with MySQL, Group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to take most frequently entered datas in last 1 day.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT tag_id, time, 
COUNT(tag_id) AS value_occurrence  
FROM   tag_rel 
GROUP BY tag_id 
HAVING time > '$yesterday' 
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC LIMIT 10
```

Code is working but it has a problem:

I wanna take between  july 22 and 23.

```
id| tag_id     | time       |
1 | football   | 22,5 july  |  
2 | basketball | 22,5 july  |  
3 | football   |  22,5 july |  
4 | football   |  21 july   |
```

I want to take first three rows and order them by their frequency.

ex:
1- football 
2- basketball

But my code is not taking "football". It just shows "basketball". Because  additionally "football" has a time value which is smaller than 22 july.

How can solve it?

Comment: Where is `value_occurrence` appearing in your output?

Comment: Hello Xaretre welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct query for what you want would use `where`, not `having`:

```
SELECT tag_id, MAX(time) as maxtime, 
       COUNT(tag_id) AS value_occurrence  
FROM   tag_rel 
WHERE time > '$yesterday' 
GROUP BY tag_id 
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Otherwise, there is an arbitrary value used for `time`, both in the `select` and the `having` clause.